# What's the "appropriate" way to listen to network state changes indefinitely on Android?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I'm working on an Android application which monitors the device's network usage in the background. As far as I know, a couple years ago the go-to approach would have been to register a `BroadcastReceiver` which catches every `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` event, but it seems like it was deprecated in Android 7. I can see a class named `JobScheduler` has been introduced since as a sort of replacement, but I'm not sure that might suit this specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ConnectivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) class to listen about connectivity change.

From official doc

> Class that answers queries about the state of network connectivity. It
> also notifies applications when network connectivity changes.

Use [registerNetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) to receive notifications about all networks which satisfy the given `NetworkRequest`

Here is sample code in Kotlin:

```
enum class NetworkResult {
    CONNECTED,
    DISCONNECTED,
    DISCONNECTING
}


class NetworkCallback : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){

    val result = MutableLiveData<NetworkResult>()

    override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(network: Network, networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities) {
        super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network) {
        Timber.i("onLost networkL $network")
        result.postValue(NetworkResult.DISCONNECTED)
    }

    override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
        Timber.i("onLosing: network: $network maxMsToLive: $maxMsToLive")
        result.postValue(NetworkResult.DISCONNECTING)
    }

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        Timber.i("onAvailable: network: $network")
        result.postValue(NetworkResult.CONNECTED)
    }
}


class ConnectivityFactory {

   fun internetRequest() : NetworkRequest{
     return NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED)
            .build()
  }
}


class NetworkConnectionManager(val context: Context){

    private val factory : ConnectivityFactory = ConnectivityFactory()
    private val callback : NetworkCallback = NetworkCallback()

    private val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val result : LiveData<NetworkResult>  get() = callback.result

    fun registerCallback(){
        val request = factory.internetRequest()
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, callback)
    }

    fun unregisterCallback(){
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(callback)
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
val networkManager : NetworkConnectionManager by lazy { NetworkConnectionManager(this)  } 

// observer state 
networkManager.result.observe(this, Observer {
    Timber.i(it.name)
})


// register 
networkManager.registerCallback()()
// unregister 
networkManager.unregisterCallback()
```